# On Boot: "The disk drive for UUID=... is not ready yet or not present"

Tags: fstab, swap, uuid

I long ago deleted and disabled my swap partition but I still get the error

```
The disk drive for UUID=d4b17eae-c547-4d02-8d1d-0279069d35f0 is not ready yet or not present
```

when booting and it is annoying.

Can I just get into `/etc/fstab` and remove the last line that says

```
UUID=d4b17eae-c547-4d02-8d1d-0279069d35f0 none            swap
```

Would it stop giving me the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what you need to do.

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

then remove the line that says

```
UUID=d4b17eae-c547-4d02-8d1d-0279069d35f0 none swap
```

Then save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)
And the problem should be gone.

Comment: i hope you know what you're saying

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
UUID=d4b17eae-c547-4d02-8d1d-0279069d35f0 none            swap
```

is saying
"There is a swap partition with id `123`, and there is no `noauto`, so we will activate it during boot.".

The UUID does not say on which disk that partition is, so the system tries to find it.
And duly notes when it fails to do so.

Now, the message you get is about a disk drive that is missing:

```
The disk drive for UUID=d4b17eae-c547-4d02-8d1d-0279069d35f0 is not ready yet or not present
```

That does make sense, because the line in `fstab` states "There is a partition 123 on one of the disk drives.". If that's true, but the partition can not be found, the conclusion is that the disk is not yet accessible.

So, it makes sense to remove that `fstab` line, because it states something wrong.
(Actually, it's a good habbit to comment it out first, and delete it later, in case it can not become useful again later)

Comment: I just put a # in front of it so that it is ignored and can be easily restored any time

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant!